# Motivation for normed space definition?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

So if $X$ is a vector space, and you define a norm, $x \mapsto \| x \|$, on it, then the bounded subset, $V = \{ x \in X: \|x\| < \infty \}$ is automatically a subspace.

This follows from the definition of a norm, so for all $x,y \in V, c \in \mathbb{C}$, $\|x + c y\| \le \|x\| + \|cy\| = \|x\|+ |c| \|y\| < \infty$, so $x+cy \in V$.

Is this the reasoning behind the definition of a norm?

Comment: In a normed vector space every vector has finite norm.

Comment: Note that for your definition $V=X$.

Answer (score 5):

The short version is that we use norms to help us study convergence in [function spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space); this is the huge subject of [functional analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis), which has applications everywhere in mathematics (PDEs, mathematical physics, probability, representation theory...).  I recommend Dieudonne's [History of Functional Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=mg7r4acKgq0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=dieudonne+functional+analysis) if you are really interested in the full story.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16522/seminorms-and-norms) might be helpful.